# Artifactory upgrade from 5.4 to 6.3.3

Tags: artifactory

I have Artifactory 5.4 running and would like to upgrade it to the latest available one: 6.3.3. Do I need to upgrade it to some interim version or can I go straight to 6.3.3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to upgrade from version 5 to 6 without the need for an interim version.

Before doing so, however, it is strongly suggested that you

1. Do a complete [system export](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting).  If at any time you decide to roll back to the older version, you can use the export to reproduce the system in its entirety.
2. Backup your database.

Comment: I have done an upgrade to 6.4 which has been just released. So far so good ... ;-)